# How can I capture the screen and ignore a specific window in the image

Tags: c#, screenshot

I want to write a program that will magnify the middle of the screen, so I used some methods from user32.dll. I managed to make my program capture the screen and refresh the image on the picturebox with 60FPS rate, but when I want to display in real time the bigger image, the program also captures my forms which displays the bigger image, thus leading to an infinite image inside an image loop. I want to capture the screen and ignore my form which displays the bigger image.

I thought about something like I pass it the handle of the window I want to ignore and it will capture anything but the window i specified. This is my code for now:

```
Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
{
    IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
    User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
    User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
    int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
    int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
    IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
    IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);
    IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);

    GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);
    GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
    GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
    User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);

    Bitmap img = null;
    try
    {
        img = new Bitmap(Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap), 1920 * 2, 1080 * 2);              
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 1080));//img.Width - (img.Height/2), img.Height));
            // g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(img.Width - (img.Height / 2) + img.Height, 0, img.Width - img.Height / 2, img.Height));
        }
        GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);            
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { }
    return img;
}
```

The handle I pass it is from this method:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
```

I already tried this solution: [How can i capture the screen without the Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16759958/8539383) 
but it didn't work well because the picturebox refreshes at 60Hz rate which causes it to stutter.

To be clear, my idea is to magnify the middle of the screen and then display the magnified image in a square in the middle of the screen (the areas outside the square will be left with their original size).

Answer (score 0):

When you capture the initial image, blank out the area that corresponds to inside your form by drawing a rectangle over the same area. You can get the window position and dimensions via the `Form` and draw the rectangle over that portion of the captured image.

Comment: What would be in that rectangle?

Comment: Anything you like but leaving it white/gray/black would be usual

Comment: I edited my question because I think you misunderstood me. If I draw a square in the middle of the screen where I display my form every frame, it will jsut stay there without the zoom I wanted because I want to display the magnified image in the form I want to ignore in the screenshot.

Comment: The drawing of the rectangle would have to happen before the zoom, not after. Unless I've misunderstood?

Comment: I added those lines:
`pictureBox1.Image = transp;
               pictureBox1.Image = sc.GetCurrentScreenImage();` but it didn't work.
`transp` is an image filled with a color that I made transparent in this form.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What are you seeing?

Comment: I am displaying the screenshot on a square right in the middle of the screen, its height is as the screen's height. the problem is that the screenshot includes the square itself that displays the screenshot, so it just displays the left quarter of the screen side by side by side inside of that square.