# Take a screenshot behind window in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm working on an app in c# windows forms, I have a form called Form1 with a button, and after click this button the idea is to take a screenshoot of everything behind it except the Form1 itself (without minimizing Form1).

Any idea or suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: This question must have been asked hundreds of times. Please do some research before asking it all over again.

Comment: I've serached it hundreds of times today but It was never answered.

Comment: Hide the form, doevents, take the shot, show the form. Note: hiding a form is not closing a form

Comment: If the answer is that the system doesn't provide a way to do this reliably then that is the answer. Just because you don't like the answer doesn't mean you should be asking the same question again. The system doesn't magically change just because you keep asking.

Comment: `this.Visible = false`  build Bitmap, derive Graphics object from it, `[Graphics].CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, [Screen].Bounds.Size);` (it's BitBlt + SourceCopy), `this.Visible = true` -- Slightly *blinking*.

Comment: You can also move the Form off-screen, then restore its location, instead of hiding it. Still slightly *blinking*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want a solution without hiding, moving, minimizing etc., you need the following approach:

1. [EnumWindows()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) to iterate all windows. This will give you the windows top to bottom.
2. Don't forget to exclude your own window
3. Exclude windows that are invisible. Check out [GetWindowLongPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptra) with `GWL_STYLE` and compare against `WS_VISIBLE`
4. [GetWindowRect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) to get their size
5. [PrintWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-printwindow) to get a bitmap of the window, no matter whether it's in the background
6. Create a bitmap with the size of the [VirtualScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.virtualscreen?view=net-5.0)
7. Paint the windows in reverse order (bottom to top) using [DrawImage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?view=net-5.0)

I found that this is quite fast (514 ms on a 2560x1440 screen with 20 visible windows to draw).

Limitations:

- since it sends a [WM_PRINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-print) message to the application, you can not capture applications that are "not responding"
- For me, Firefox does not render well. It's missing page contents.
- For me, control panel content appears black, although it's there when getting a screenshot of the whole screen.

Comment: This idea sounds fantastic, but it would be great to take the entire destkop screenshot. However I will test this suggested approach and see.

Comment: @PierreSaintBermudez The entire desktop will contain your form.

Comment: Whether or how an application implements its `WM_PRINT` handler is a decision made by every single application. Not providing a handler is a common decision. Expect this to fail.

Answer (score -1):

you can use hard code. Actually light shot and other tools working such as. When you click to screenshot button you may close the form window after the event and reopen it. it is the basic way of solution...
Please check this way: [How can i capture the screen without the Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759958/how-can-i-capture-the-screen-without-the-form)

Comment: What do you mean by `hard code`? Is that something like 'hard ware'? :D There is also a difference between closing and hiding a form. Your answer should be a comment pointing to the existing answer, but you probably can't do that yet. ;)